# Why the distinction between WMMA and "just" MMA instructions?

Tags: cuda, intrinsics, ptx, cuda-wmma

After reading the answer to this question:

[Does PTX (8.4) not cover smaller-shape WMMA instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146946/does-ptx-8-4-not-cover-smaller-shape-wmma-instructions)

and re-reading the [section](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#warp-level-matrix-multiply-accumulate-instructions) of the PTX ISA reference distinguishing WMMA from MMA instructions, I wonder - why the distinction?

That is,

- Why do some of the instructions get the `w` prefix? After all, some of the non-w MMA operations are warp-wide...
- Why don't we just have `mma.load` and `mma.store` warp-wide instructions which can take care of the loading data into registers?
- Why is there no coverge by intrinsics and templates (e.g. `fragment<...>`) of all of the matrix-multiply-add-related PTX instructions?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: You're right, the title was a mis-copy-paste.